# Access SELECT statements giving me errors

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to populated a Temp Table with some data from my queries. The problem I came across is trying to SELECT certain data using 2 WHERE criteria. As long as I have one, it pulls up the correct data and populates it as such. However, when I try to filter by two criteria (which I need to do in order to pupulate info in correct rows), it gives me an error "TYPE MISMATCH". What happens is, after my first criteria WHERE = " & lngCompanyID    - There is no quote at the end of it, however, when I add another criteria... WHERE CompanyID = " & lngCompanyID and UnitPrice = " & lngUnitPrice " <--- there is a double quote at end of it and I think it's stopping it from passing the value. This is what the code looks like

```
With rs2
    While Not .EOF
        rs2.Edit
        lngCompanyID = rs2("CompanyID")
        lngUnitPrice = rs2("UnitPrice")
        strSQL2 = "SELECT SumOfInvQty from qryAddx WHERE InvValue = " & lngUnitPrice And CompanyId = " & lngCompanyID"
        Set rs3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)
            If rs3.recordCount > 0 Then
              rs2("Added") = rs3("sumofinvqty")
              rs2.Update
            End If

        rs2.MoveNext
        Set rs3 = Nothing
    Wend
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not continuing you're concatenation of the string correctly. Try this instead:

```
With rs2
    While Not .EOF
        rs2.Edit
        lngCompanyID = rs2("CompanyID")
        lngUnitPrice = rs2("UnitPrice")
        strSQL2 = "SELECT SumOfInvQty from qryAddx WHERE InvValue = " & lngUnitPrice & " And CompanyId = " & lngCompanyID
        Set rs3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)
            If rs3.recordCount > 0 Then
              rs2("Added") = rs3("sumofinvqty")
              rs2.Update
            End If

        rs2.MoveNext
        Set rs3 = Nothing
    Wend
End With
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: @barry17 no worries, please accept the answer if you're happy :)

Comment: if I wanted to add mode data to my TEMPTABLE within the same loop, would that be possible? in this code I'm selecting data from qryADDX, but i aso want to select data from qryUSEDx and populate the next column with it. I'm trying to do this as effieciently.